# If statement regex in bash with plus operator

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I'm sure this is a simple oversight, but I don't see it, and I'm not sure why this regex is matching more than it should:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ ([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+ ]]; then
{
  echo "found list of jobs"
}
fi
```

This is with input that looks like "02,48,109,309,183".  Matching that is fine

However, it is also matching input that has no final number and is instead "09,28,34,"

Should the `[0-9]+` at the end dictate the final character be at least 1+ numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add markers for beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of input:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "found list of jobs"
fi
```

Otherwise it matches `09,28,34,` because it matches from `0` until `4`, ignoring everything that follows.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex only has to match *somewhere in the string*, not from start to end. To make it match the whole string, use the `^` and `$` meta-characters:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "found list of jobs"
fi
```

(Incidentally, you don't need `{` and `}` to define a block in Bash, that's the job of `then` and `fi`)

Comment: Looks nice! but it won't match '02,48,109,309,183'

Comment: Don't ask me! :) As I said: Looks nice

Comment: Ah, my mistake, you can't use single-quotes like that apparently. I'll edit them back out.

Comment: Yeah! now it works! @speakr Sorry, I were wrong. Without quotes it works.  deleted comment. +1 for you both! :)

Comment: No clue how to pick the resolved answer for this...can't I pick two?? :(